# C - writing and reading a dynamical array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to create a 2D array for storing names (with max 50 characters each). I have written a code, but it isn't working properly, where's the problem? (I can do this with statics arrays, however at the beginning my program won't know how many names I will want to store in the array). Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n=5;
    int size=51;
    char *a_name=(char*)malloc(n*size*sizeof(char));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",&a_name[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        printf("%s\n",a_name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "not working properly" is not a problem description. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not an array of `char` but an array of `char *`.
Try this:

```
int n = 5, size = 51;
char **name_array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    name_array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    // You may initialize the array first.
    scanf("%s\n", name_array[i]）； 
}
```

Remember to release the memory when you no longer need the names.